# error in google map integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to integrate the google api i have found some codes for that

API Script

```
<!-- Dependencies: JQuery and GMaps API should be loaded first -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<!-- CSS and JS for our code -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-gmaps-latlon-picker.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-gmaps-latlon-picker.js"></script>
```

html code

```
<fieldset class="gllpLatlonPicker">
    <input type="text" class="gllpSearchField">
    <input type="button" class="gllpSearchButton" value="Search">
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="gllpMap">Google Maps</div>
    <br/>
    lat/lon:
        <input type="text" name="gllpLatitude" class="gllpLatitude" value="30.44867367928756"/>
        /
        <input type="text" name="gllpLatitude" class="gllpLongitude" value="70.6640625"/>
    zoom: <input type="text" name="gllpZoom" class="gllpZoom" value="4"/>
    <input type="button" class="gllpUpdateButton" value="update map">
    <br/>
</fieldset>
```

this code working fine separately but when i integrate in my application it 
shows me that error

[image]

Comment: js code where you have initialized map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

In the above script the tag sensor is not required in "src" instead of that please provide a googlemapapi key, it will work!!

eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=paste your key here"></script>
```

Get your key:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key
Thanks!!!

Comment: but it work fine with separately and i have use the same code in front end of my website thats work fine but not working in the backend

Comment: SensorNotRequired Warning 
The sensor parameter is no longer required for the Google Maps JavaScript API. It won't prevent the Google Maps JavaScript API from working correctly, but we recommend that you remove the sensor parameter from the script element.

Comment: i have removed sensor parameter but still have that error (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).gMapsLatLonPicker is not a function)

Comment: are you sure you added Googleapi key ??